# Can't align <div> to center

Tags: css, html, alignment

I'm trying to align a 'div' attribute to the center of the page (horizontally). The problem is that whatever attributes I've used, the 'div' continues to be aligned to left. The 'div' which I am reffering to, is the page 'div' of the webpage, which is inside the 'html' and the 'body' attributes. Here's the CSS code:

```
#page{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;

    overflow:auto;

    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;

    width:1200px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:12px;    
    height:700px;
}
```

and the 'html', 'body' CSS code is the following:

```
﻿html,body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Note that if I remove the "overflow" property, the div is aligned to the center of the page (although, it overlays the menu which is on top of it) but I need the "overflow" property to automatically add scrollbars if the width/height of the page which would be displayed inside this div is greater than those specified in the CSS.

Comment: Have you tried "0 auto" instead of just auto as margin parameter?

Comment: Show your full code in jsfiddle plz

Comment: Yes, I have tried 0 auto but it didn't help either...

Answer (score 4):

I haven't coded anything in awhile, however normally when I am creating a centered page:

```
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
```

Then for the div:

```
#page { width: 900px; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; margin: 20px 0 20px 0; }
```

That may or may not work, like I said, it has been awhile.

Answer (score 3):

It seems your **div** is filling full screen width. So center alignment will not have any **visible** effect on the div. Try to use a **span** instead.

**Following will NOT work**

```
<body style="text-align:center">
  <div>Foo</div>
</body>
```

**Following should work**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span>Foo</span>
</body>
```

> 

Answer (score 2):

In order to margin:auto works in your case is required to have a defined width/height for your main containers which are HTML and BODY

**IMPORTANT**:Both HTML and BODY elements must be ruled with the width/height properties

Do as follows

```
html,body {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
   width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

and watch this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/gHB52/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="margin:0px auto;">sfsfsafafas</div>
```

Use this code surely it will make the div to center.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

**HTML**

```
<div id="page"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page {
  width: 350px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #000; margin: auto
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5h2JZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at the "left" and "right" attributes for centering a  if you are trying to center horizontally.

For instance, if your width was 60% of the page (width:60%), you could set (left:20%) and (right:20%) which MAY center it, however that depends on how your div is positioned. (position:absolute) or (position:relative).

(position:absolute) with the above width, left, and right should center horizontally.

There is also `<center> enter code </center>` within HTML that has worked for me in the past.

I'm not a guru with this though, so I don't know what "best practice" to use in your case.